# How to add an event and change when a link is copied?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a javascript function to change the link that has been copied by a user. With right-click > Copy link. I searched around, I tried adding an `onclick` event but nothing. I searched for something with `document.addEventListener` but nothing. Please give me help.

Comment: I don't think there's an event for that. There's a `copy` event, but it's triggered when the user copies a selection from an input field.

Comment: try an onclick listener with this navigator.clipboard.readText()
  .then(text => {
    console.log('Pasted content: ', text);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
  }); on a 3 second timeout to see if the clipboard has the link

Answer (score 0):

The thing thatI understand is that you want to change a link when it is copied to different on

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="https://www.google.com" id="demo" oncopy="myFunction()">Link1 is here</a>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Link1 changed to Link2"
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want the copied link to change then it is not possible : Instead you can replace the link with your choice before the copy that is initial link of your choice

The oncopy event occurs when the user copies the content of an element.
**Tip :** The oncopy event also occurs when the user copies an element, for example, an image, created with the  element.
**Tip :** The oncopy event is mostly used on  elements with type="text" but can be applied to other elements also.